# Android GLES 2.0: post-multiplying by matrix doesn't work

Tags: android, matrix, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I seem to have found that post multiplying a vector with a matrix in a a vertex shader works on my desktop machine but not on my Android phone.

I'm using libGDX and GLES2.0 to write a game. I got a decent chunk of it working on desktop, but when I tried to run it on Android it just showed blank clear-color. By messing around I discovered the problem was only there when I was using a matrix in my vertex shader. The vertex shader in question is:

```
attribute vec3 aVertPos;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;

uniform mat4 uCamMatrix;
uniform vec3 uPosition;
uniform vec2 uSize;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
  vTexCoord = aTexCoord;

  vec3 scale = vec3(uSize,0.0);
  vec4 dest = vec4((aVertPos*scale)+uPosition,1.0) * uCamMatrix;
  gl_Position = dest;
}
```

I found I still got the blank screen even if I passed uCamMatrix as an identity matrix. Utterly puzzled, I looked around at other shaders and - without expecting a result - switched the order of the matrix and vector in that line:

```
vec4 dest = uCamMatrix * vec4((aVertPos*scale)+uPosition,1.0);
```

I had been transposing the matrix before passing it, so I stopped doing that since I was changing the order. This totally fixed the issue.

The desktop version looks the same as it always did, so the calculation result must be the way it was before.

So does Android/GLES20 have some quirk about matrix multiplication? Is this a bug? Am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: Sounds like you're doing the right thing to me, my guess is a bug.

Comment: What device / chipset / GL driver? I'm experiencing a similar problem on the 2nd gen Nexus 7 tablet with a Qualcomm Adreno of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a matrix multiplication bug, then the code below should solve the problem. (But to be honest I think that the problem must be somewhere else in your code).

The code transposes the matrix, so the matrix can be located on the left side of the vector (This is done in an very unefficient way - you should only use this code to check if the matrix multiplication is done correct).

```
attribute vec3 aVertPos;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;

uniform mat4 uCamMatrix;
uniform vec3 uPosition;
uniform vec2 uSize;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
  vTexCoord = aTexCoord;

  vec3 scale = vec3(uSize,0.0);
  vec4 dest = transpose(uCamMatrix) * vec4((aVertPos*scale)+uPosition,1.0);
  gl_Position = dest;
}

mat4 transpose(mat4 m){
    return mat4(
            m[0][0],m[1][0],m[2][0],m[3][0],
            m[0][1],m[1][1],m[2][1],m[3][1],
            m[0][2],m[1][2],m[2][2],m[3][2],
            m[0][3],m[1][3],m[2][3],m[3][3]
            );
}
```